# How to detect window close event that was opened using window.open()

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I am trying to detect the window close event that I opened using `window.open()` in javascript. But for some reason, it doesn't seem to work.

Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
   <script>
     var clicktest = function() {
        var newwindow = window.open("https://www.google.com",'myPopupwindow', "height=640,width=960,toolbar=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,location=no,status=no");
        newwindow.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (e) {
          console.log('hey');
        });
     }
   </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="clicktest()">hey</button>
</body>
</html>
```

I also tried using

```
newwindow.onbeforeunload = function () {
    console.log('hey');
}
```

instead of `window.addeventlistener()`, but both didn't work and I did try using `window` instead of `newwindow`, still, it didn't work.

Comment: Please define "_it doesn't seem to work_".

Comment: All examples I saw about the onbeforeunload event relate to the current window. I'm not sure you can catch this event from a different window. Moreover, in your current code there is a violation of the same-origin policy: your JavaScript code tries to access a resource on a different domain (www.google.com) - opening the window works fine, but further attempts to interact with it using JS will be blocked by your browser. See this question and answer for more on that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098021/securityerror-blocked-a-frame-with-origin-from-accessing-a-cross-origin-frame

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888902/detect-browser-or-tab-closing

Comment: You could listen `focus` on the current window (not on the pop-up), and check `newwindow.closed` value. That is a boolean which is `false` as long as the pop-up is open, and when closed, the value is switched to `true`.

Comment: Your code works if the opened website has same origin. If the other website is external then you simply cannot.

Answer (score 1):

For cross-origin documents, the only solution is to poll the `.closed` property of the popup Window object.

But that is a very ugly thing to do, so please have a second though about why you need that.

To limit the ugliness, you can power your polling using battery friendly [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame):

```
const popup = window.open('https://google.com');
waitForClose(popup, e=>console.log('closed'));

function waitForClose(win, cb) {
  function poll() {
    if(win.closed) {
      cb();
    }
    else {
      requestAnimationFrame(poll);
    }
  }
  poll();
}
```

[As a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tghLw89v/) since StackSnippet's iframes don't allow popups.

Comment: Listening `focus` on the main window will do the trick without "ugly polling". User has to blur the main window in order to close the pop-up, and when coming back to main window `focus` will fire.

Comment: @Teemu not at all, if opened as a tab, you can close it while keeping focus on the main doc, and you may also never come back to the main win but still want to know the other one got closed.

Comment: @Teemu and then they'll at least have their own beforeunload event to fire. Look, the question asks for an event, IMM getting the notice 20 minutes after can not be called "an event", they can't listen to the ones of the outer doc, so the closest thing to an event they can have is by polling this property.